# event parameter and its purpose

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hey everyone today i have a question about the event parameter. might sound a bit noobish but there are a few things i would like clarified for myself.

1.) does the (event) parameter or (e) have a default value? as in does javascript already define this within its programming.

2.) if so, in the case of this code snippet from jquery.com, does javascript understand the event that the anchor tag performs and thats where the .preventDefault comes into play.

3.) i ask this obviously to understand but im pretty sure javascript does have some predefined parameters. if not then i think i answer my own question that it is just defined by the value the parameter is given.

thank you for your help

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>event.preventDefault demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<a href="http://jquery.com">default click action is prevented</a>
<div id="log"></div>

<script>
$( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $( "<div>" )
    .append( "default " + event.type + " prevented" )
    .appendTo( "#log" );
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The event object is passed from the event queue when the handler will be called. The object exists only when an event occurs, and the object is defined specifically for each event. However, jQuery event model is different. It grabs the queue call, copies the passed event object, normalizes it, and then calls the original handler, passing the copied event object instead.

Comment: ... and to be accurate, JavaScript doesn't create events, they are a [part of DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events).

Answer (score 0):

> in the case of this code snippet from jQuery.com, does JavaScript understand the event that the anchor tag performs and that's where the .preventDefault comes into play.

It's worthwhile to first clarify that the anchor tag alone does not perform an event. The anchor tag is just markup that encodes particular uses/functions... mainly, the ability to let the user navigate to a different URL (as specified by the tag's `href` attribute). Rather, it's you (*i.e.,* the user) that performs the event. The browser only knows to redirect you to that anchor tag's URL when you click on it.

The important point to take away is that certain actions/events on certain elements have default behaviours encoded into them. They are the default behaviors. For example:

- a click on an anchor tag (*i.e.*, a link) navigates you to another address
- a click on `input` elements of either the `checkbox` or `radio` types checks the checkbox or filles the radio button, respectively
- a right-click on many elements brings up a context menu
- pressing 'enter' on a form field submits it to the server

So, yes, your question points to the right idea. JavaScript understands to disable those default behaviors (that is, to *prevent the default actions*) that are ordinarily executed for certain events on certain elements.